# How to tell IntelliJ not to warn me about request attributes can not be being resolved in jsp files?

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea

This is what I am talking about:

[image]

Well IntelliJ is complaining that it can not resolve username or email. Is there anyway to tell IntelliJ not to make this inspection for variables that will be in request attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question:

Forcing

```
requestScope.username
```

avoids this warning..